# Young adult book about a girl pulled through a mirror by her soulmate

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, parallel-universe

My daughter is looking for a young adult, or maybe kids, book that she read about a normal girl who one day notices a boy looking back at her through a mirror. Then he pulls her through into another world where they have dragons as familiars, there are talking cats and everyone has a corresponding person/soulmate/double of some kind.

It's supposed to be part 1 of a series or just has a sequel.  It ends in a cliffhanger, and she can't figure out what the book was to finally read the sequel.  She doesn't remember any character names.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like the "*Magical States of America*" series by John Peel. Description of the first book, ["*Suddenly Twins!*"](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6828868-suddenly-twins):

> It all began the day Chrissie Scott looked into the mirror and saw
> somebody else's reflection. A boy who looked exactly like her. Nothing
> would ever be the same again...
>
> **Suddenly Twins!**
>
> Chrissie thought she had troubles -- until she fell through the mirror
> into her double's life. He said his name was Chris, and his world was
> the mirror image of hers. His world was ruled by magic -- and about to
> be destroyed by the sorceress Lori Lee!
>
> Chris is desperate. He has cast a powerful spell and sees the evil
> plot. Chrissie is the only one he can trust. Together they must save
> his world before it's too late. But is Chrissie about to be lost
> forever in the universe beyond the mirror?

[image: Suddenly Twins! front cover]

Goodreads lists the sequel as ["*Twice the Trouble!*"](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8599757-twice-the-trouble).

Answer (score 2):

This could possibly be Philip Pullman's [*His Dark Materials*](http://www.philip-pullman.com/hdm) trilogy, although some of the details don't match.

In that series, it is the girl - Lyra - who is from the world where everyone has a familiar, and there are talking polar bears, not cats.

In the second one, Lyra gets into our world, and meets a boy, Will. I don't recall anything about a mirror though.

(Even if it's not a match, it's still well worth reading.)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the second book from [*His Dark Materials*](http://www.philip-pullman.com/hdm) by Philip Pullman. Will is the boy and Lyra is the girl. They enter different versions of each other's worlds through windows that Will cuts open with a knife. It's called *The Subtle Knife*. Lyra has a 'demon', a companion that can change shape into different animals/insects that talks kinda like Jiminy Cricket from *Pinocchio*.